# Taking a server from development to production

Tags: wcf, security, server

I have created a service (WCF) that acts as a backend for a DB. For now it does basic operations such as INSERT, SELECT etc. I have run it locally and now it is time to expose her to the internet and enter 'production'. Is there a best practice to doing so? Bear in mind this service will be hosted on a PC as a Windows Service (not IIS). This is the first time I am putting a Windows Service into production so I am hazy on the details but I think this is the main idea:

1. On the service: Check for 'rookie' errors such as SQL Injection. Set maximum message sizes to ones marginally higher than the largest message that should be transmitted by my service. Also upgrade self signed X.509 certificate to one issued by a CA. (Where does one store this certificate? Locally on the PC?)
2. On the PC: Fully patched software (OS etc) and windows firewall with a specific set of rules that allows traffic only on the ports being used (I suppose the safest way to do this is to use the windows tool **Allow a program or feature through Windows Firewall** ?). Furthermore an updated antivirus running.
3. On the Network: For the network router, port forward the respective ports being used (the base address is declared as `http://localhost:8080` so I guess port 80 for HTTP and 443 for HTTPS? I am using message level Security.)
4. General precautions: Full message logging on the service to analyze traffic and potential attackers. Also run a Network intrusion detection system such as Snort so that I can sleep a bit better at night.

Am I missing anything obvious? Also should I be hosting in IIS, on security exchange someone said that I would be vulnerable to HTTP attacks if I did not put the code behind a web server. However I have not read this anywhere else

Comment: Do you always refer to your services in the third person feminine? ;)

Comment: We have a very intimate relationship.